# Incrementally increasing volume in Bash

Tags: bash, volume, mplayer

I'm making an alarm clock and wanted to start at basically no volume and increase the sound per 2 seconds up one 'notch'/value until a certain predefined point where it won't increase anymore.

As of right now I'm using `mplayer` (it's a radio station, so I'm running `mplayer http://66.225.205.192:80`), but I don't care what I use (VLC, etc.))

My full code is

```
while true; do
  mplayer http://66.225.205.192:80
  sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Ive seen http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/advaudio-volume.html but im not good enough to really use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for 'mplayer alarm clock' actually yields a lot of pages dealing with this problem and solutions that you can actually use right away, but let's give it a try anyway.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    for ((volume = 0; volume <= 100; volume += 5)); do
        /usr/bin/aumix -v${volume} -w100 >/dev/null
        sleep 2
    done
} &

mplayer http://66.225.205.192:80
echo "good morning! :-)"
```

You need to install `aumix`, which is used here to change the volume (but you could use something else, of course). The block between `{` `}` gets run in the background. The `aumix` command sets the PCM volume to 100% and gradually adjusts the main volume in 5 percent increments every two seconds, once it hits 100% the loop finishes and the background job exits.

I have never used `aumix`, and you might want to read its man page in case it does not work as expected (this is untested).

`mplayer` runs in the foreground until you quit it, upon which it <strike>makes coffee for you</strike> greets you with a warm welcome.

Does that get you started?